# Sorting values input by a user using array

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on an HTML/javascript project: here is the pertaining parts of code so far
HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>String Sorter</title>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="strings.css" />

<script src="strings.js"></script>
</head>

<body>


<div id="headers">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="floatright">
                <h3>  </h3>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <h3>Input</h3>
        </td>
        <td>
            <h2><pre>   Length</pre></h2>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>


<table id="data">
<tr>
    <rd class="after"><label id="label1">1</label></rd>
    <rd class="after"><input type="text" id="1" /></rd>
    <rd><span id="number1">0</span></rd>
</tr>
</table>


<table>
<tr>
    <td>
        <button type="button" id="addBtn">Add Cell</button>
    </td>
    <td>
        <button type="button" id="removeBtn">Remove Cell</button>
    </td>
    <td>
        <button type="button" id="sortBtn">Sort</button>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>


<p id="test"></p>
<script>setup()</script>
</body>
</html>
```

javascript

```
    seen = 1;
total = 1;

function setup(){
plusBtn = document.getElementById("addBtn");
plusBtn.addEventListener("click", addFunction);
deleteBtn = document.getElementById("removeBtn");
deleteBtn.addEventListener("click", removeFunction);
filtBtn = document.getElementById("sortBtn");
filtBtn.addEventListener("click", sortFunction);
input1 = document.getElementById("1");
input1.addEventListener("change", count);

}


function addFunction(){
if(seen < total){
    i=findLatest();
    i2=i+1;
    latest=document.getElementById(i2);
    latest.style.visibility = "visible";
    number=document.getElementById("number"+i2);
    label=document.getElementById("label"+i2);
    number.style.visibility = "visible";
    label.style.visibility = "visible";
    seen++;
}
else{
    temptot= +total+1;
    tab = document.getElementById("data");
    row = data.insertRow(total);
    //cell1 = row.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<span><label id="label2">2</label></span>');
    //cell2 = row.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<span><input type="text" id="2" /></span>');
    //cell3= row.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend','<span id="number2">0</span>');
    cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
    var itemLabel = document.createElement("Label");
    itemLabel.setAttribute("id", "label"+temptot);
    itemLabel.style.visibility = "visible";
    itemLabel.innerHTML = total+1;
    cell1.appendChild(itemLabel);
    var input = document.createElement("Input");
    input.id = temptot;
    input.type = "text";
    input.style.visibility = "visible";
    cell2.appendChild(input);
    var spanTxt = document.createElement("Span");
    spanTxt.setAttribute("id", "number"+temptot);
    spanTxt.innerHTML = "0";
    spanTxt.style.visibility = "visible";
    cell3.appendChild(spanTxt);
    input.addEventListener("change", count);
    seen++;
    total++;
}

}

function removeFunction(){
temp=document.getElementById("2");
temp2=document.getElementById("number2");
temp3=document.getElementById("label2");
if(temp.style.visibility != "visible"){
    return;
}
else{
    i=findLatest();
    latest=document.getElementById(i);
    number=document.getElementById("number"+i);
    label=document.getElementById("label"+i);
    latest.style.visibility = "hidden";
    number.style.visibility = "hidden";
    label.style.visibility = "hidden";
    seen--;
}

}

function sortFunction(){
max = findLatest();
var holder = new Array();
for(i=1;i<=max;i++){
    temp=document.getElementById(i);
    temp2=temp.value;
    holder.push(temp2);
}
holder.sort();
for(j=max;j>=1;j--){
    item = holder(j-1);
    check=document.getElementById(j);
    check.value = item;
    holder.pop();
}

}

function count(){
//temp=document.getElementById(this);
temp= this;
temp2=temp.value.length;
lengt=document.getElementById("number"+this.id);
if(lengt.firstChild != null)
    lengt.removeChild(lengt.firstChild);
lengt.appendChild(document.createTextNode(temp2));
}

function findLatest(){
table=document.getElementById("data");
//for(i=2; i<=total; i++){
for(i=1; i<=total; i++){
    temp=document.getElementById(i);
    if(temp.style.visibility == "visible"){
       if(parseInt(i)==parseInt(total)){
        return i;
       }
       else if(i==1 && document.getElementById("2").style.visibility == "hidden"){
           return 1;
       }
       else{

        }
    }
    else if(document.getElementById(i).style.visibility == "hidden" && document.getElementById(i-1).style.visibility == "visible" ) {
        return i-1;
    }

}

}
```

CSS:

```
    html{
background-color: cyan;
}




h2{
font-style: normal;
font-weight: bold;
}

h3{
font-style: normal;
font-weight: bold;
}

.floatsmall
{
float: right;
width: 1000px;
}


.floatright
{
float: right;
width: 80px;
}

tr.number{

}

.after {
padding-top:0px;
padding-right: 6px;
padding-bottom:0px;
padding-left: 0px;
}
```

Everything works great except my sort function. What I am trying to do is pull the data from each input element and push it into an array. Then I am attempting to sort that array and then pop the data back into the elements in correct order. However, this is not working and my attempts at debugging look like the array isnt being filled in the first place... any ideas?

Comment: Whats the `rd` element? Is that a typo? Should it be `<td>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is likely at this line:

```
item = holder(j-1);
```

where you probably meant

```
item = holder[j - 1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this line in `sortFunction`:

```
item = holder(j-1);
```

Should be:

```
item = holder[j-1];
```